# Undefined Index in PHP after Using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

It seems that this question has already been asked many times but none of the solution is working for me. I'm new to AJAX so maybe there are some basics that I've missed? Basically I just want to pass the content of an html paragraph to a PHP script and I don't want to use html form.

I have two files: tes.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#post").click(function(){
          var getContent = $("#text").html();
          $.ajax({
             url:"tes.php",
             type:"POST",
             data:{text:getContent},
             dataType:"html",
          });
       });
     });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="text" contenteditable="true">This is the content</p>
    <a href="tes.php" target="_blank"><button id="post">post 2</button></a>
</body>
</html>
```

and tes.php

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['text'])) {
        $content = $_POST['text'];
        echo $content;
    } else {
        echo "no content";
    }
?>
```

After I clicked the Post button, in the PHP file it returns

> **Notice**: Undefined index: text in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\lab\tes.php on line 3.

Where did it go wrong? Really need your help guys. Thanks!

Comment: why is the error located in tes.php and you link test.php?

Comment: sorry, in the original code it is actually linked to tes.php. I changed the code for this question.

Comment: Well, undefined index can only mean that the server isn't receiving the $_POST['text'] variable... what happens if you remove the `$content = $_POST['text'];
        echo $content;` and replace it with `print_r($_POST);` (just for debugging)

Comment: I notice now it says on line 3... which means that the variable is set... I'm confused.. Is this error notification actually relevant to the code?

Comment: it returned an empty array.. Array()

Comment: Then my theory, that the server isn't receiving the context is correct. That means there's a problem with the html/javascript side, and not the php side.

Comment: can you show us the code in tes.php, since you show us the test.php code? I think you're trying to ask for help with the wrong problem.

Comment: it's exactly the same with the code shown above.

Comment: you are only posting to test.php, but not to tes.php, that's why the error occurs in tes.php and not in test.php, that is how I understand the isuse, with the data you give us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#post").click(function(){
      var getContent = $("#text").html();
      $.ajax({
         url:"tes.php",
         type:"POST",
         data:{text:getContent},
         dataType:"html",
         success:function(data) {
          console.log(data)
         }
      });
   });
 });
```

and in the HTML (as reza suggested)

```
<button id="post">post 2</button>
```

then, open the developer console and see if you can see the response from the tes.php

Comment: Hi @Christian! Yes, I can see the response. Many thanks! Thanks also to @reza

Answer (score 0):

change html

```
<a href="tes.php" target="_blank"><button id="post2">post 2</button></a>
```

to

```
<button id="post">post 2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `click` event and that sends an AJAX request so far, so good. You have

```
target="_blank"
```

which makes sure the page is opened in another tab/window. As far as I understood, you only want to send the request, so you need to prevent default:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#post").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var getContent = $("#text").html();
          $.ajax({
             url:"tes.php",
             type:"POST",
             data:{text:getContent}
          });
       });
     });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="text" contenteditable="true">This is the content</p>
    <a href="tes.php" target="_blank"><button id="post">post 2</button></a>
</body>
</html>
```

The new tab/window will give you the error, since an expected parameter is not there, so don't open it.